# Iteration over numeric Array in javascript returns strings

Tags: javascript

Why

```
for (i in [1, 2, 3]) console.log(typeof(i), i);
```

gives this:

```
[Log] string 0
[Log] string 1
[Log] string 2
```

I've expected numbers.

@ Safari 7.0 (9537.71), Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: JavaScript's `in` keyword is always for keys/properties, not values. [`for-in`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) iterates keys and the [`in` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.7) checks for the existence of keys. To get a value, you need to use a [property accessor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1): `arr[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because an `Array` in Javascript is a special `Object` with property keys (which are strings) used as indices.
you are iterating that `Array` like an `Object` and because of that `i` is seen as a property `key`, a string.

To iterate in the right way an `Array` you have to use the following:

```
for( var i=0; i < [1,2,3].length; i++){ ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

[Try instead](http://jsconsole.com/?var%20arr%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0Afor%20(var%20i%20in%20arr)%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(typeof%20arr%5Bi%5D%2C%20arr%5Bi%5D)%3B):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i in arr)
    console.log(typeof arr[i], arr[i]);
```

You're getting `string`s rather than `number`s because [`for..in` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterate keys/properties (in this case, the `Array`'s indices) rather than values.

To get the value of each key, `i`, you'll have to use a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators), `arr[i]`.

---

Though, why strings at all rather than the original number indices is because, with current standards, [all properties are strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1).

```
console.log(Object.keys( ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] )); // ["0", "1", "2"]
```

Any value can actually be used with property accessors, but it'll be converted `ToString()` before it's actually used as a key/property.

> 6) Let *propertyNameString* be [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*propertyNameValue*).

[`Map`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and `Symbol`s are currently planned to be the exceptions to that.

---

Also, you may find "[*Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)" of interest and at least consider using a simple `for` loop instead:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++)
    console.log(typeof arr[i], arr[i]);
```

Though, for future reference, the upcoming [ECMAScript 6 standard](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts) has added [`for..of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which should iterate as you were expecting.

```
for (var i of [1, 2, 3])
    console.log(typeof i, i); // number, 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: The Q was: why strings? Ok, it's easy to guess that I get "indexes" instead of values. But the fact that indexes are strings was very unexpected. Now I understand that it's a "bug by design". .. Thank you for your post, it's well-formed and very useful, but it's not the exact answer for my question.

Comment: @akaRem Ah. Sorry. I guess I read it more as: "*why* those *strings*?" I've added an explanation for "*why strings?*" Though, "*bug by design*" is an odd choice of description. I can understand wanting to disagree with the behavior being what it is, but it's still [well-defined and standardized](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). So, it's not a "*bug*."

Comment: Ok, it's just bad design. :)